# How to predict the selected image by user is invalid image or wrong image in image processing using CNN

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, prediction

I am creating a leaf disease prediction app using Deep learning. I need to validate my app, i.e., need to show an error page or 'invalid image' popup if the user selects an invalid image. I am not getting any videos related to this on YouTube. It would be great If I could get the solution:)

I tried searching for it on google and YouTube but didn't get any solution regarding this. I am expecting to get the solution for the same. Need to get the invalid image message.

Comment: What is an invalid image and how do you detect it?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to validate my app. i.e., if the user selects an image other than a tomato leaf,  I want to show an error message.

Comment: Doing that is much more difficult than you think, it is basically out of distribution detection, and in the end it is not a programming problem.

Comment: _"I am not getting any videos related to this on YouTube"_ why do you restrict yourself to only youtube? the internet is more than youtube, and knowledge is more than just the internet. why do you expect there to be an exact solution to your problem anywhere?

Comment: Thank you for your kind responses. Does this mean in a beginner-level project I cannot include the said feature right?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.